# error in this C++ program

Tags: c++

When i run this program i get the below mentioned error in line    `s<<"\""<<string<<"\""` :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
string str="abc";
stringstream s;
s<<"\""<<string<<"\"";
cout<<(s.str().c_str());
```

error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<<' token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

http://codepad.org/KuyMQg3x , here is the online code with error .

Comment: Did you mean `str` instead of `string`?

Comment: you put string as variable name (too late :)

Comment: same error , after correction .

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string str="abc";
    stringstream s;
    s<<"\""<<str<<"\"";
    std::cout<<(s.str().c_str());

}
```

as suggested in the comment changing string to str works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute code at the top level instead of inside a function. This is what your program should look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str="abc";
    stringstream s;
    s<<"\""<<str<<"\"";
    cout<<(s.str().c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing your main function. Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str="abc";
    stringstream s;
    s<<"\""<<str<<"\"";
    cout<<(s.str().c_str());
}
```

The `C++` runtime needs a function to run to start your program, it will always run `int main()` (or `int main(int argc, char* argv)`)